# NuGet: jQuery Mobile install error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, jquery-mobile, nuget

I created an empty MVC 2 Empty Web Application, then use NuGet to upgrade my project to MVC 4. After that I use NuGet to install jQuery Mobile, but get errors. Here is the whole error messages

```
Attempting to resolve dependency 'jquery (≥ 1.6.4)'.
Installing 'jQuery 1.6.4'.
Successfully installed 'jQuery 1.6.4'.
Installing 'jquery.mobile 1.3.2'.
Successfully installed 'jquery.mobile 1.3.2'.
Adding 'jQuery 1.6.4' to MvcApplication1.
Successfully added 'jQuery 1.6.4' to MvcApplication1.
Executing script file 'C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MSCExpress\MvcApplication1\packages\jQuery.1.6.4\Tools\install.ps1'.
Executing script file 'C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MSCExpress\MvcApplication1\packages\jQuery.1.6.4\Tools\uninstall.ps1'.
Failed to initialize the PowerShell host. If your PowerShell execution policy setting is set to AllSigned, open the Package Manager Console to initialize the host first.
Uninstalling 'jQuery 1.6.4'.
Successfully uninstalled 'jQuery 1.6.4'.
Install failed. Rolling back...
Failed to initialize the PowerShell host. If your PowerShell execution policy setting is set to AllSigned, open the Package Manager Console to initialize the host first.
```

I am using Visual Studio 2010. I have found this [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c934fed4-e44e-4a06-9e3b-eccb9c8aa8d6/mvc-4-package-installation-error-in-vs-2010) closed to my situation and tried it but still get the error messages. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Adding jQuery mobile yourself is extremely easy

just follow the instructions on http://jquerymobile.com/download/

Comment: Manual adding jQuery mobile works fine. I am just trying to figure what is going on, what is wrong.